# datetime period with optional months

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, format, jodatime

I`m trying to build formatter in JodaTime to parse Period from strings like these:

- year 1hour 90min
- 1year -60days 800min
- 1year +1months -1days +1hour -30min

I know I can build parser with PeriodFormatterBuilder in jodatime but with it I can`t parse first two examples

```
 PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendYears().appendSuffix("year", "years").appendSeparatorIfFieldsAfter(" ")
    .appendMonths().appendSuffix("month", "months").appendSeparatorIfFieldsAfter(" ")
    .appendDays().appendSuffix("day", "days").appendSeparatorIfFieldsAfter(" ")
    .appendHours().appendSuffix("hour", "hours").appendSeparatorIfFieldsAfter(" ")
    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("min", "mins").appendSeparatorIfFieldsAfter(" ")
    .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("sec", "secs")
    .toFormatter();
```

Is there any way I can tell joda that tose fields are optional?

Comment: Why do you have mixed signs in your input? I am just curious. In strict sense, that is not a single duration (period), but a sequence of durations. For example: Is 1month - 30days in the future or in the past??? Very strange. - About your question itself: Joda-Time has no concept of optional sections in parsing periods (only seconds with optional millis, not more). Maybe a specialized `PeriodParser` helps, but I would recommend to apply a tokenizer first (simpler).

Comment: Did the PeriodParser implementation help you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanna achieve this, you can do so by writing a custom parser. For this you will have to implement PeriodParser class and implement the parseInto() method.

```
@Override
public int parseInto(ReadWritablePeriod period, String periodStr, 
                     int position, Locale locale) {
    String tokens[] = periodStr.split(" ");
    period.addYears(0);
    period.addMonths(0);
    period.addDays(0);
    period.addHours(0);
    period.addMinutes(0);
    period.addSeconds(0);
    for (String token : tokens) {
        int count = 0;
        if (token.contains("year")) {
            String years = token.substring(0, token.indexOf("year"));
            period.addYears(years.length() > 0 ? Integer.valueOf(years) : 0);
            continue;
        }
        if (token.contains("hour")) {
            period.addHours(Integer.valueOf(token.substring(0, token.indexOf("hour"))));
            continue;
        }
        if (token.contains("min")) {
            period.addMinutes(Integer.valueOf(token.substring(0, token.indexOf("min"))));
            continue;
        }
        if (token.contains("months")) {
            period.addMonths(Integer.valueOf(token.substring(0, token.indexOf("months"))));
            continue;
        }
        if (token.contains("day")) {
            period.addDays(Integer.valueOf(token.substring(0, token.indexOf("days"))));
            continue;
        }
    }
    return periodStr.length();
}
```

After that use the following code to create a formatter and parse the period.

```
PeriodFormatterBuilder builder = new PeriodFormatterBuilder();
PeriodFormatter formatter = builder.append(null, new MyParsePeriod()).toFormatter();
```